# Identity Server 3 error : User is not active. Redirecting to login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identityserver3

I am stuck with this problem:

I am using Identity Server 3 with ASP.Net Identity. When I reset my password the first time everything works fine and I am able to log in with my new password.

Now when I try the forgot password feature a second time, Identity Server does not recognize the new password and throws me an invalid username password error.

After some digging and debugging I found out that IdSrv does not have a fresh DB context and that's why it does not find the new password.

I tried overriding `UserServiceAuthenticateLocalAsync` and I forced the authentication to succeed like this :

```
 context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult(user.UserName, user.UserName);
```

Now I am getting these logs:

```
IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.AuthenticationController|Login credentials successfully validated by user service
IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.AuthenticationController|Calling PostAuthenticateAsync on the user service
// Some more logs...
IdentityServer3.Core.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator|User is not active. Redirecting to login.
```

I don't know why IdSrv is saying that my user is not valid.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Most likely because the user hasn't been activated yet. If you have a custom userservice implementation, you can do your check in the [IsActiveAsync method](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Services/IUserService.cs#L77). The check is done in the [AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/5949af67a3ece0d56bbaf0bdbf9bfa1c36d3b2c3/source/Core/ResponseHandling/AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator.cs#L130)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @scheien, is there a way to activate the user manually inside my custom `UserService` ? How does the method  `IsActiveAsync` check if the user is active or not ?

Comment: If you don't have any specific conditions for activation, you can just assign `true` to `context.IsActive`. Otherwise you would need to implement some more logic depending on what your rules are.